# Memory management when doing multitasking in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4

According to Apple... apps should reduce their memory footprint as much as possible when running in the "background" (suspended mode).  I reduce the memory footprint of my app by releasing a bunch of 2D textures in ApplicationDidEnterBackground and reloading the same textures in ApplicationWillEnterForeground.  Everything works for the most part.

Here is my question:  Why do I get a SIGABRT or EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when I move my app to/from the background rapidly?  The errors occur when the app is coming back into the foreground (textures are being reloaded).

I don't receive any errors when I move the app to/from the background less rapidly.  How can I prevent this?  Perhaps I should be checking if the resources are actually deallocated before I try to reload them?

How does one **code defensively** in this situation?

Comment: I have heard that will enter foreground can be called before did enter background on a rapid switch.  Code defensively.

Comment: i'm sure you already know, but you get that error when you send a message to a released object. it's hard to be specific with this example.

Comment: @drawnonward: If that's the case, you might consider keeping track of what's executed first. Not necessarily the best programming practice, but one that should work.

Comment: One defensive move that could help: set your textures = nil after deallocating, that way you're not in danger of sending messages to a garbage address.

Comment: try running with NSZombiesEnabled, it will at least tell you which object is being messaged, anything that gets released should be set to nil, as this way if you message it, nothing will happen, instead of your program blowing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an older question, but let me take a stab.  You mentioned releasing 2D textures.  Are you using Cocos2D perchance?

I had a similar issue to yours earlier this year - the issue wasn't with my code.  It was with Cocos2D's - there was a bug where textures could get purged at the same time as loading new textures asynchronously.

I've reported the issue, and it seems like a February commit to the Cocos2D project also addressed a similar problem.